# Query to build a messages system from different joined tables

Tags: php, mysql

This code below is working but the output is not what i really want.
We have different tables in database:

Table users:

```
id  firstname        lastname        company
1   user1_firstname  user1_lastname  company_user1
2   user2_firstname  user2_lastname  company_user2
```

Table messages

```
id  userid  motivation                     article_id  date_created
1   1       Motivation text from buyer 1       1       date_created1
2   1       Motivation text from buyer 1       1       date_created2
3   2       Motivation text from buyer 2       1       date_created3
```

Table articles

```
id  userid  title                explaination                 date_created
1   3       Title for article 1  explaination for article 1   date_created1
2   3       Title for article 2  explaination for article 2   date_created2
```

Table messages_sellers

```
id  userid_buyers  message_id  reaction                         article_id  date_created
1   1              1           Reaction from seller to buyer 1      1        date_created1
2   2              2           Reaction from seller to buyer 2      2
```

And the code:

```
      $article_id = $_GET['article_id'];

      $sql = "
      SELECT 
         u.firstname, 
         u.lastname, 
         u.company, 
         m.motivation,
         ms.reaction,
         m.userid as message_id_buyer,
         a.id as article_idx,
         a.explaination,
         a.date_created as datecreated_seller,
         m.id as message_id,
         group_concat(CONCAT(m.motivation, '&&', m.date_created) SEPARATOR '----') as motivations,
         group_concat(CONCAT(ms.reaction, '&&', ms.date_created) SEPARATOR '----') as reactions
      FROM 
         messages m 
      LEFT JOIN 
         articles a 
      ON 
         a.id = m.article_id
      LEFT JOIN 
         users u 
      ON 
         a.userid = u.id 
      LEFT JOIN
         messages_sellers ms
      ON
         ms.message_id = m.id
      WHERE 
         m.article_id = '$article_id'
      GROUP BY
         a.id
      ORDER BY
         m.date_created desc
      ";

      $res = mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());
      $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($res);

      if($num_rows > 0) {

      while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
   ?>    

                   <!-- Explaination from seller for article -->
                   <article class="review-box clearfix">
                      <div class="rev-content" style="margin-left: -90px !important;">
                         <h3 style="text-transform: none !important;"><?php echo $row['firstname']; ?> <?php echo $row['lastname']; ?> (<?php echo $row['company']; ?>) | <?php echo date('d-m-Y H:i', strtotime($row['datecreated_seller'])); ?></h3>
                         <div class="rev-text">
                            <p><?php echo $row['explaination']; ?></p>
                            <a href="?article_id=<?php echo $row['article_idx']; ?>&userid_buyer=<?php echo $row['message_id_buyer']; ?>#add-review" class="theme-button marT10">Post your reaction</a>
                         </div>
                      </div>
                   </article>


                <?php 
                $motivations = $row['motivations'];
                $motivations_array = explode('----',$motivations);

                if(is_array($motivations_array) && count($motivations_array) > 0 ){

                    foreach($motivations_array as $motivation_name){ 
                        $arr = explode('&&',$motivation_name);

                        if(!empty($arr[1])){
                ?>    

                   <!-- posting motivations -->
                   <article class="review-box clearfix" style="margin-bottom: -5px !important;">
                      <div class="rev-content">
                         <h3 style="text-transform: none !important;">Uw antwoord verstuurd op <?php echo date('d-m-Y H:i', strtotime($arr[1])); ?></h3>
                         <div class="rev-text">
                            <p><?php echo $arr[0]; ?></p>
                         </div>
                      </div>
                   </article>

                <?php } } } ?>




                <?php 
                $reactions = $row['reactions'];
                $reactions_array = explode('----',$reactions);

                if(is_array($reactions_array) && count($reactions_array) > 0 ){

                    foreach($reactions_array as $reaction_name){ 
                        $arr2 = explode('&&',$reaction_name);

                        if(!empty($arr2[1])){
                ?>    

                   <!-- Posting reactions on motivations -->
                   <article class="review-box clearfix" style="margin-left: -90px !important;">
                      <div class="rev-content">
                         <h3 style="text-transform: none !important;">Uw reactie verstuurd op <?php echo date('d-m-Y H:i', strtotime($arr2[1])); ?></h3>
                         <div class="rev-text">
                            <p><?php echo $arr2[0]; ?></p>
                         </div>
                      </div>
                   </article>

                <?php } } } ?>
```

The output is as follows:

```
Explaination for article seller 1
   motivation message buyer 1 for article seller 1
   motivation message buyer 1 for article seller 1
   reaction back from buyer 1
reaction seller 1
```

But what i want is the following:

```
Explaination for article seller 1
   motivation message buyer 1 for article seller 1
   motivation message buyer 1 for article seller 1
Reaction seller 1
   reaction back from buyer 1
```

Anyone who can help me out here?

This is for a messages system where buyers have to post a motivation message to the sellers, so the seller can decide on who he will sell his product. It is like a webshop but a little bit different in communication.
Buyers can give a reaction back on the message of the seller.

I think the query is correct but not the output.

Comment: It would probably help if you provided the sample data that produces that sample output.

Comment: **Side note:** Your SQL looks so neat and tidy....but then you went and messed it up with `$article_id = $_GET['article_id'];`......`m.article_id = '$article_id'`.....and then with `mysql_*`. You probably should fix this sql injection issue and deprecated database library before you implement this script. You may not be able to do a `LEFT JOIN users` some day if you don't.

Comment: @PatrickQ: i have updated my code with sample data

Comment: @Rasclatt: i will use PDO or mysqli if i implement this working example. No worries.

Comment: Maybe it is possible to work with a self-referencing table here? Anyone who can help me to build the query for that inclusive the output code?